# Best ultra short throw (UST) projector technique for text (journal club, PDF, powerpoint)

Tags: 4k, projector

I would like to buy a ultra short throw (UST) projector for education at University.

The projector will be used for presentations with a lot of text and some detailed graphs (PDF, powerpoint). However, since sometimes also some movies will be shown, it should be 4K.

We recently tried the Epson EH-LS800W but unfortunately the text was quite blurred and sometimes some colors of the graphs were missing. Unfortunately, we could not solve this problem and others had [the same problem](https://www.reddit.com/r/projectors/comments/162ifol/epson_ls800_blurry_and_potential_chromatic/?rdt=65467).

It was mentioned [that the DLP technique might be better than LCD for text](https://www.avsforum.com/threads/epson-eh-ls800w-blurred-text-and-missing-color-with-4k.3285615/#post-62872152). However, I did not find other sources supporting this statement.

1. Which projector technique (LCD, DLP, LCoS, etc.) is the best for sharp text?
2. Is there any UST projector that is especially useful for text presentations?